# Coexistence of Intel AMT and AMD DASH in SCCM 2012 R2

Tags: sccm, intel, amt, out-of-band-management

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Intel AMT and AMD DASH plug-ins in SCCM 2012 R2 to out of band manage clients?

I've successfully implemented the Intel AMT plug-in, now I'm wondering if I can also implement the AMD DASH plug-in on the same SCCM console. Someone got experience on this matter? I'd love to hear experiences and how-to's if something needs to be done.

I'm asking this because we've got a lot of Intels, but also AMDs. And we want to be able to manage both from the same platform.

Comment: Could not add "amd, dash" tags. If someone can edit these in, might help getting more answers?

Comment: If [tags](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/create-tags) don't exist yet, then nobody will be monitoring them either... So creating a new tags will not really increase the visibility of your question. I added the more generic (burt seldom used) out of band management tag though.

Comment: @SanderC [You cross-posted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625404/coexistence-of-intel-amt-and-amd-dash-in-sccm-2012-r2).  You should pick a site and remove the other one.  See [the cross-posting policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).